# Set Global Variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to set global variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("a.action").click(function(event) {
            var tempResponse = "";
            $.get("", function(response){
                tempResponse = response; 
            });
            alert("response " + tempResponse );
      }

       //todo use response to manipulate some data
});
```

I declared globa variable `tempResponse`. and I set in get call back function.

```
tempResponse = response;
```

but while I try to alert the response no data displayed. I also try this solution. I change the variable declaration
become `$.tempResponse` and change the set script become `$.tempResponse = response;`

But it doesn't work to.

Why this could  be happened ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you call the alert before the variable is actually set. Remember that you are performing an asynchronous query when you call `$.get`. Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('/somescript.cgi', function(response){
        alert('response ' + response);
    });
});
```

Comment: I wanna use the response outside the $.get function scope. I just use alert to simplify my code.

Do you have another suggestion ?

Comment: There's no other suggestion. You cannot use something that's not been assigned yet. You could still use the global variable to assign its value but you cannot use it immediately after the `$.get` function.

Answer (score 3):

I believe setting the global variable in the top of the script, then setting the ajax call to async: false will do exactly what is needed.

This way the ajax finishes before the javascript attempts to assign the variable.
Plus the ajax function is cleaner to me than using .get.

```
tempResponse = null;
$.ajax({
    url: 'whatever.cgi',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { blank: null }
    success: function(data) {
         tempResponse = data.response;
    }
 }).error(function(){
    alert('Ajax failed')
 });

 alert(tempResponse);
```

In your script that is returning the "response", make sure its in json format.  In php I would make the data into an array like

```
$json_data = array('response'=>$var_name_php_for_response_value);
```

then only echo out the needed data like so:

```
 json_encode($json_data);
```

This would produce the format: `{ "response":"some response text" }` which is the correct json format.

Comment: nice one, I needed this solution!

Answer (score 0):

You are just calling your alert right after the $.get so the tempResponse is not yet ready

Comment: this script call while a anchor link clicked 
$("a.action").click(function(event) {
var tempResponse = "";
//so on
}

Answer (score 0):

To make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tempResponse = "";
    $.get("", function(response){
        tempResponse = response; 
        alert("response " + tempResponse );
    });
});
```

Notice your alert is now inside the json callback function; this function does not execute until the json query is done

Comment: I wanna use the response outside the $.get function scope. I just use alert to simplify my code. Do you have another suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you have to wait for the ajax to finish.
use `ajaxComplete()`

if you have:

```
var tempResponse = "";
    $.get("ajax/test.html", function(response){
        tempResponse = response; 

    });
```

you could:

```
$('.log').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
  if (settings.url == 'ajax/test.html') {
    alert("response " + tempResponse );
    $(this).text('Triggered ajaxComplete handler.');
  }
});
```